Blazor server, Timers, Disposing and Cannot access a disposed object
I use Timer in the main components of our app. It's used to trigger an endpoint every few minutes to tell us that the user is active on the application.
The code looks like this inside MainLayout.razor:
@implements IDisposable
.
.
.
    private System.Threading.Timer Timer ;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Timer  = new System.Threading.Timer(_ =>
        {
            if (applicationUser.LogedIn)
            {
                InvokeAsync(updateLastSeen);
            }
        }, null, 240000, 240000);
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        Timer ?.Dispose();
        Timer  = null;
    }

This works most of the time, but we sometimes see this exception. This results in application restart.
 warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteRenderer[100]
       Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot access a disposed object.
       Object name: 'Timer'.
       System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
       Object name: 'Timer'.
          at System.Timers.Timer.set_Enabled(Boolean value)
          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallbackFactoryBinderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass32_0`1.<CreateBinderCore>b__0(ChangeEventArgs e)
       --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
 fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
       Unhandled exception in circuit 'wO6hOy44Wd0kK3zpgb5w4E-9Frulb4mArReLXZ89NkI'.
       System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
       Object name: 'Timer'.
          at System.Timers.Timer.set_Enabled(Boolean value)
          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallbackFactoryBinderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass32_0`1.<CreateBinderCore>b__0(ChangeEventArgs e)
       --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)

As far as I can see, we followed instructions from the docs.
Does anyone have an idea about the source of the problem here?

tell us that the user is active on the application. you already know that, and the timer won't help. You have a Blazor server application which means the timer code runs on the server. Each user session creates a SignalR circuit so you know who the active users are. Should the user close the browser or lose connectivity, the SignalR circuit will be terminated. The underlying SignalR client already sends keepalive messages to the server. Check ASP.NET Core Blazor SignalR guidance

The Monitor Server-side Circuit activity section seems to do what you want already - detect whether a user is idle for a specific period even before the circuit gets closed

The error is occuring in CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion which only gets called if there's an async operation in either OnParametersSetAsync or a UI event handler.  I don't see either of those here, so I don't think you've provided enough information to answer the question.

@PanagiotisKanavos
Thanks for your answer! That is true, but I try to make my components work in both WASM and Server projects. So that is not a valid mitigation for me. I would like to get to the source of the problem and solve it, not avoid it.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis
Thank you very much for your answer!
This component does not override OnParametersSetAsync, but it does also override OnInitializedAsync.
There are many UI event handlers in this project, but a few in this component. I would be glad to share more info about this that would help me debug a problem, but I'm not sure what event handler to look for.

@Marko what you did prevents the component from running properly in either WASM or Server. You made the hard-coded assumption the code runs on WASM so you need an extra timer. But the timer itself is in the wrong place for WASM, will fail if pre-rendering is enabled and OnInitialized gets called twice, and does nothing at all in Server. If you really want to ping some other API from WASM, create a BackgroundService that pings it. On Server mode, you don't need the timer at all

@Marko besides the real requirement is 1000% a server requirement: Finding out the current active users. That means a server-side eg UsersCatalogService with implementations that gets updated either from a polling API or SignalR hub events. The polling API is only needed for WASM. In WASM, what you really need is a Hosted service on the client that hits the server

You probably need to put some logging in to see where the exception is occurring.  Log each call to OnInitializedAsync and if it's noy there then add logging to the UI Handlers.  Once you know where post some code if you can't figure it out yourself.

@PanagiotisKanavos
Thanks for commenting, and workaround suggestions. But I would really like to get to the source of the exception and find out why it breaks only every few days. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

@MrCakaShaunCurtis
Thanks for your dedicated time.
I've already moved this code into a small component that will be included in MainLayout.Razor. Hopefully, that way, it won't be affected by other UI event handlers. I also removed InvokeAsync, since the method does not need a UI thread.

@Marko I already explained what the source of the exception is. Wrong assumptions that resulted in incorrect code, that doesn't do what you assumed

@Marko the method does not need a UI thread. on the contrary, Blazor Server has the same semantics as a desktop application. The user circuit is equivalent to the UI thread, causing the same problems. You can't have two different threads sending DOM changes to the same tab

@PanagiotisKanavos The method does not do any kind of DOM interaction. It only triggers the API endpoint. And it does work most of the time.
If we were to forget the logic around checking user state, and so on, and imagine that it needs to increment a counter, it would be throwing the very same exception.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis You were right. The exception had nothing to do with the code i posted, exception source is in Blazored.Typeahead libary!
